# How to set sprites to numbers in a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, pygame

I would like to know how to set different sprites as different numbers in a matrix. So for example if I had a matrix of:

`[[ 2 -1  1  0  1  1]
 [-1  0  2  0  3  1]
 [ 0 -1  0 -1  1  2]]`

How would I add a certain enemy for the 1's, 2's, 3's, etc. in the certain spot that the number appears.

The numbers in the matrix are randomly generated. Here is my code so far:

```
from random import *
import numpy as np

rows = 3
cols = 6

matrix = np.matrix(np.random.randint(-1,4, size=(rows, cols)))
```

What I want to do:

```
def create_enemies():
    for int in matrix:
        if int == 1:
            enemy = Enemy()
            enemy_group.add(enemy)
        if int == 2:
            enemy2 = Enemy2()
            enemy_group.add(enemy2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        position = matrix[i][j]   
        if position == 1:
            enemy = Enemy() 
            matrix[i][j] = enemy
            enemy_group.add(enemy)
        elif position == 2:
            enemy = Enemy2() 
            matrix[i][j] = enemy
            enemy_group.add(enemy)

        else:
            enemy = Enemy3() 
            matrix[i][j] = enemy
            enemy_group.add(enemy)
```

A better solution would be to just set the random sprites in the matrix, and avoid setting the numbers altogether. Something like:

```
import random
class Dog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

class Cat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

class Pig:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
rows = 6
cols = 3
choices = [Dog(), Cat(), Pig()]

matrix = [[random.choice(choices) for i in range(rows)] for j in range(cols)]

print(matrix)
```

Comment: The second variant is nice, but I think `choices` should rather contain the classes and the instances should be created in the list comp, otherwise you create a matrix which only consists of references to the three instances in the `choices` list.